# Delay websocket connection with react-use-websocket

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I have a component that uses `react-use-websocket` to instantiate a websocket.  The socket needs authentication and since I can't use headers to pass the token, I need to pass it in the query parameters.

However, the initial websocket connection fails, because the token is not yet provided.  After the initial connection times out, it attempts to reconnect, this time with the correct access token.

Is there a way to delay the initial connection until the token is populated/updated?  The token is stored in the redux state.

```js
const accessToken = useSelector(state => state.auth.access.token);

const getSocketURL = useCallback(() => {
    let url = new URL(`ws://${window.location.hostname}:8001/ws/commands`);
    if (accessToken) url.searchParams.append('token', accessToken);
    console.log('URL', `${url}`);
    return `${url}`;
}, []);

const { readyState, getWebSocket } = useWebSocket(getSocketURL, {
    share: true,
    retryOnError: true,
    shouldReconnect: (e) => true,
    reconnectInterval: 4,
    reconnectAttempts: 2,
    onError: (e) => console.error('Error in websocket', e)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Documentation it seems that `useWebSocket` accepts a third argument `shouldConnect`that defaults to true.

So setting it to false when there is no token should work:

```js
const { readyState, getWebSocket } = useWebSocket(getSocketURL, {
    share: true,
    retryOnError: true,
    shouldReconnect: (e) => true,
    reconnectInterval: 4,
    reconnectAttempts: 2,
    onError: (e) => console.error('Error in websocket', e)
}, 
   Boolean(accessToken)
);
```

Comment: How would you then initiate the connection once the token is valid?

Comment: It does it automatically,  when the accessToken value change, the `useWebSocket` hook should be called again with `Boolean(accessToken)` now with the value true.